# Select some indexes in a list of lists

Tags: f#

I have a record type which holds a list of table rows. Each row is also a list. The first row is assumed to be the header row. In addition the type optionally defines a filter - a list of columns (the actual string value of the column header).

Then the type have a member property `FilteredRows`. If no filter is defined, the property is the entire table. But if there is a filter, `FilteredRows` return the list of rows, but only with the columns defined by the filter.

I'm not interested in alternative ways to represent this. This is part of a bigger solution, it's working, and the design makes sense to me. What I believe I need however is some more eyes on the internals of `FilteredRows`. I'm looking for clever tricks on solving this problem in different ways, and other pointers on how I can improve the solution.

```
type Table = 
    {
        Rows : string list list
        OnlyColumns : string list option
    } 
    member internal x.FilteredRows =
        match x.OnlyColumns with
        | None -> x.Rows
        | Some xs -> 
            let indexesToInclude = seq {
                let headers = List.head x.Rows
                for c in xs do
                    yield List.findIndex ((=) c) headers }
            x.Rows
            |> List.map
                (fun row ->
                    indexesToInclude
                    |> Seq.map (List.nth row)
                    |> List.ofSeq )
```

As you can see, what I've done is first to fetch all the column indexes using `List.findIndex`. And then for each row I map over the column indices and re-create the row using `List.nth`.

Comment: It was really difficult to create a good title for this question :/

Comment: Well, it says something about the code, so it's better than many titles we often see here :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real change that pops out at me without touching the record datatypes is to make `indexesToInclude` an array, you're evaluating it over and over again in that seq comprehension each time. Since it's an array and lookups are fast, and you know its size, you might as well pre-allocate it instead of using a comprehension which will be much faster. Then do a mapi over the rows, and just look up if you want that index in the array.

```fsharp
type Table = 
    {
        Rows : string list list
        OnlyColumns : string list option
    } 
    member internal x.FilteredRows =
        match x.OnlyColumns with
        | None -> x.Rows
        | Some xs -> 
            let headers = List.head x.Rows |> List.toArray
            let isIncluded = Array.init (headers.Length) (fun hi -> xs |> List.exists (fun lv -> lv = headers.[hi]))
            x.Rows
            |> List.map (fun row -> row |> List.mapi (fun i v ->  (isIncluded.[i], v))
                                        |> List.filter fst |> List.map snd)
```

The most important thing here is that we're no longer indexing into a list (almost always a bad idea in F#), which costs O(n) where n is the index you're indexing into. If you do this every time it gets very expensive!

Comment: I like this solution. It's similar to mine in principle, but better. I tend to forget `mapi`, which you use to great effect here.

Comment: I decided to use your solution, so I accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

```
type Table = 
{
    Rows : string list list
    OnlyColumns : string list option
} 
member internal this.FilteredRows =
    match this.OnlyColumns with 
    | None -> this.Rows
    | Some columns -> 
        let indexOfColumn name = this.Rows |> List.head |> List.findIndex(fun x -> x = name)
        let selectors = columns |> List.map (fun column -> let ci = indexOfColumn column in (fun (row : string list) -> row.[ci]))
        let projectRow row = selectors |> List.map (fun f -> (f row))
        this.Rows |> List.map (fun row -> row |> projectRow)
```

Consider these performance characteristics:

- indexOfColumn is run once per included column, which will be O(n^2) for linear search over the list of columns, which is hopefully small in comparison to number of rows
- selectors are functions to take a whole row to a selected column by index - if index lookup on a list is constant time, then a selector will run in constant time
- the projectRow function projects a whole row to the set of selected columns. This can be parallelized if required, but it will run in O(n) where n is the number of *included* columns
- projectRow is called exactly once per row in the list

Comment: I find this solution interesting, something to learn from, yet it's a bit harder to understand (from my perspective).